# ajax response have call javascript function

Tags: jquery, ajax

html code  `< div class="stl"> < /div>`

```
jQuery('.y72_ig').on("change",function() {
mainurl = "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : mainurl+'/awaiting_payments_ajax.php',
            data: {
                "t_uid" : kkl,
            },
            success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            }
        });
}});
```

what I got in console log in response:

```
jQuery('.y72_ig').on("change",function() {
mainurl = "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : mainurl+'/awaiting_payments_ajax.php',
            data: {
                "t_uid" : kkl,
            },
            success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            }
        });
}});
```

and the other code that awaiting_payments_ajax.php generated.

my question is ajax is returning the calling jquery scripts in response with awaiting_payments_ajax.php generated codes.if I write `console.log(response)`

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have in  awaiting_payments_ajax.php will be return as a response of ajax call.

What you have in  awaiting_payments_ajax.php?

Comment: a lot of php generated html codes, I am getting all jquery scripts where the ajax scripts with the response

Comment: If that is visible to your console you can print the same in your html.

Comment: the full javascripts moved in the response ,its visible if I write console.log(response)